# std:: pair in unordered map

Tags: c++, loops, set, unordered-map, std-pair

I've extracted the sections of my code to show what I believe is causing the error.

```
        typedef unordered_multimap<string , ItemPtr > StringToItemMultiMap;

        void Library::multiMapItemWithKeys ( StringToItemMultiMap * map , ItemPtr itemPtr , StringSet keySet )
    {
        StringSet::iterator it;
        for ( it = keySet.begin ( ); it != keySet.end ( ); ++it )
        {
            pair< string , ItemPtr > aPair ( *it , itemPtr );
            map->insert ( aPair );
        }
    }
```

I have this operator overload:

```
    bool operator<(const ItemPtr & ip1, const ItemPtr & ip2)
    {
        bool result;
        if ( ip1.getPtr ( )->getTitle ( ).compare ( ip2.getPtr ( )->getTitle ( ) ) < 0 )
            result = true;
        else
            result = false;
        return result;
    }
```

This is a typical error:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: asgmt04, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  Library.cpp
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xhash(672): error C2675: unary '++' : 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
    1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\unordered_map(632) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,true>>::insert<_Iter>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Kty=std::string
    1>  ,            _Ty=ItemPtr
    1>  ,            _Hasher=std::hash<CustomType>
    1>  ,            _Keyeq=std::equal_to<CustomType>
    1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,ItemPtr>>
    1>  ,            _Iter=std::string
    1>          ]
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: there is also a typedef statement I left out

Comment: typedef string CustomType;

Comment: The code you posted doesn't account for the error - you should try to create a small, standalone program that recreates the problem, the you can then post here and get help with.  (Chances are you'll discover your mistake just trying to create that program.)  If you do fix your problem - or post a better one - I recommend using the `C++` tag on the question, otherwise few of the people who could help you are likely to notice it.